# Anchor tags not centering properly

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am currently creating some pages as part of the Free Code Camp CSS challenges.

For some reason my  tags are not properly centering once I collapse the grid upon the @media activation. They keep slightly drifting to the right side.

The link for the complete pen is here:

https://codepen.io/alioshr/pen/KKPBPMr

I have already tried using inline-block display, justify-self to center, etc.

```
<html>
<header id="header">
  <figure>
    <img id="header-img"src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0866/9666/files/checkout_logo_4_1024x2_37df55d3-8344-46fb-8913-ea64de22f564_500x.png?v=1509363172">
  </figure>
  <div>
  <h1>Doce Meliponicultura</h1>
      <p>Reconnect with Mother-nature</p>
  </div>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#top-features" class="nav-link">Top Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#products" class="nav-link">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#social" class="nav-link">Social</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
</html>

<style>
a {text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;}

#header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  background: gold;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header {grid-template-areas: "title" "logo" "nav-bar";}
  #header > figure {grid-area: logo;}
  #header > div {grid-area: title;}
  #header > nav {grid-area: nav-bar;}
}

#header > figure {
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
  display: relative;
  max-height: 140px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header > figure {
    justify-self: center;
  }
}

#header > nav {
  justify-self: end;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header > nav {
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: can't tell which tag you are referring to

Comment: It would appear that you're mixing CSS Grid syntax with Flexbox syntax. I don't think that things like `align-items` and `justify-content` have any affect when items are set to `display: grid`. I also think that Flexbox is easier to use in the beginning than CSS Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below CSS in your @media (max-width: 600px)

```
#header > nav > ul{
     padding: 0px;
}
```

It will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks so much! Simple and effective!

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my answer as well, to give a bit more info about Flexbox set up. Basically I removed all the CSS Grid syntax in favor of Flexbox. I'm not sure what exactly you're going for, but this will give you an idea of how to get it working at a minimum.

```
#header {
  display: flex;
  background: gold;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header {
     flex-direction: column;
  }
}

#header>figure {
  justify-self: flex-start;
  align-self: center;
  max-height: 140px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header>figure {
    justify-self: center;
  }
}

#header>nav {
  justify-self: flex-end;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #header>nav {
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
```

Here is my working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/4k0qdrao/12/) (the codepen link you supplied never loaded for me).

Here is a really great resource on learning what all the Flexbox rules do, etc

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I am studying the grid deal right now. I will build another page based on Flex. Thanks anyway.